# iOS: How to check if cellular data usage is on for an app?

Tags: ios, reachability

In my app I want to be able to detect if the cellular data usage is on for a particular application, and depending on the result of the check act appropriately.

Is there a way to perform this programmatic check?

Comment: **Answer**: Use the well-documented [Reachability framework provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/introduction/intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/introduction/intro.html

download and import the header and iplementation file, then use this code:

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    NSLog(@"Cellular data");
}
```

This project is a little old, you might need to turn ARC mode off see this answer:

[How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658549/1880431)

Comment: thank you for your answer! but this code checks if cellular is on. It doesn't check if cellular data is on for a specific app installed on the phone.